# Which is correct way to create new custom theme in magento 2.0.4 under pub/static/frontend folder or app/design/frontend folder?

Tags: magento-2.0.4

Which is correct way to create new custom theme in magento 2.0.4 under pub/static/frontend folder or app/design/frontend folder ?

Answer (score 1):

All your code should go in the app/ folder.

The pub folder is used by magento to generate static view files.

Please see: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

And use this as a starting point for theme development in magento2: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 1):

You should develop your custom theme in `app/design/frontend/` and you can deploy static content to `pub/static/frontend/` using command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`. You should not create anything inside `pub/static/frontend/`. During development you should delete everything inside `pub/static/`, `var/cache/`, `var/page_cache/`, frontend`var/generation/` and deploy you content using above command.

Here is basic theme configuration example which goes inside app/design/frontend/MyStore/MyAbstract/

**theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Mystore</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent>
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
</theme>
```

**registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/MyStore/MyAbstract',
    __DIR__
);
```

Put preview image preview.jpg (you can change name is theme.xml) inside media directory and you should see your theme in admin section store configuration.